# Azure VM extention Failed to Delete

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Azure VM extension installed on windows server. But its status is unavailable. Unable to uninstall it.

```
Failed to delete the virtual machine extension
Failed to delete the virtual machine extension 'AzureNetworkWatcherExtension'. Error: error
```

Answer (score 1):

Every extension has logs inside the VM, check `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins<extensionName>` and see if they tell you why it fails.

Sometimes when extensions seems to be stuck, [redeploying](https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/redeploy-to-new-node-windows) the VM to new nodes and then retry to uninstall/install them have worked.

Comment: Those servers are done ASR. There is no folder called C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins<extensionName>. Uninstall take more than 1 hour and failed.

Comment: @nomad Thats weird, I have servers migraed with ASR which all got the folder. Can you install any extensions at all? Maybe there is some restriction inside your VM which prevent Azure from creating the logs and then fails?

Comment: Every extension installation same as that.

Comment: Is the VM agent installed and running? Get-AzVM -name <vmanme> | Select -ExpandProperty OSProfile | Select -ExpandProperty Windowsconfiguration